# How do i re-size a banner without cutting it off?

Tags: css

I am using width: 100% and height: 250px. If i choose anything smaller than 250px, it cuts off my banner. if i change the size of image it distorts. Is there a way to resize without having it cut off or distorted but keep same proportions?
Here is my CSS:

```
#banner {
    background-image: url('banner.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
header {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    left: 245px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<header class="main-header">
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="nav-menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Items</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: With such little knowledge,this is a shot in the dark. Have a div with the image as a background, set to cover. Adjust padding-bottom as a percentage within the div until it is the right proportion. Div will resize with the browser and keep proportion intact.

Comment: You can't have an img tag with width 100% and a fixed height and pretend  it to be not distorted. If you want the image to take the whole width, just set the height to auto

Comment: Remove the image tag, and make it a `background image`. Then set it to `no-repeat` and set the size to `width: 100%`, `height: auto`. Then set the background position to`center center`...

Comment: I'm sorry i'm really new... how do i put the code in grey boxes so it looks neat

Comment: @A.Sharma Can you help me with this?

Comment: Get rid of the no-repeat from the background image styling. It should be in its own: background-repeat: no-repeat

Comment: Add background-position:center center as well

Comment: @A.Sharma, When i put in the `height: auto;`, the image disappears... any thoughts:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the CSS [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property. Setting value to `contain` will resize your image to fit its container. Additionally, you can set the background image position (if you do not want it to be centered):

```
#banner {
    background-image: url('banner.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

**contain**

> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed
>   within the container. When the image and container have different
>   dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are
>   filled with the background-color.  The image is automatically centered
>   unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.

Comment: Thank you @skobaljic, it did not center the image till i used `background-position: center;`